# Как конвертировать мой файл .txt в .json в bash?

Tags: json, bash

У меня есть такой текстовый файл txt (где * это какой-то текст):

```
[ Some ping ], 1..7 pings
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
not ok  1  ********* ****** ******* ************ (**** ***), 6ms
not ok  2  ********* ****** ******* ************ (*** ** ** ***, *** ***), 24ms
ok  3   ********* ****** ***** (*** ** ** ***, *** ***), 21ms
ok  4  ********* ****** ******* **** (**** ***), 10ms
ok  5  ********* ****** ******* **** (*** ** ** ***, *** ***), 17ms
ok  6  ********* ****** ******* ****** (**** ***), 11ms
ok  7  ********* ****** ******* ****** (*** ** ** ***, *** ***), 28ms
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5 (of 7) pings passed, 2 ping failed, percents as 61.23%, spent 127ms
```

Я ищу способ преобразовать это в json, как это:

```json
{
"MainHead": Some ping",
"pings":[
{
"head": "********* ****** ******* ************ (**** ***)",
"result": false,
"time": "6ms"
},
{
"head": "********* ****** ******* ************ (*** ** ** ***, *** ***)",
"result": false,
"time": "24ms"
},
{
"head": "********* ****** ***** (*** ** ** ***, *** ***)",
"result": true,
"time": "21ms"
},
{
"head": "********* ****** ******* **** (**** ***)",
"result": true,
"time": "20ms"
},
{
"head": "********* ****** ******* **** (*** ** ** ***, *** ***)",
"result": true,
"time": "17ms"
},
{
"head": "********* ****** ******* ****** (**** ***)",
"result": true,
"time": "11ms"
},
{
"head": "********* ****** ******* ****** (*** ** ** ***, *** ***)",
"result": true,
"time": "28ms"
}
],
"total": {
"good": 5,
"bad": 2,
"percents": 61.23,
"time": "127ms"
}
}
```

Я пока нашел только такое решение, но оно не дает той картины которую я хочу получить.

```
   jq -Rs '[ split("\n")[] | select(length > 0) | split(":") | {head: .[0], result: .[1], time: .[2]} ]'  text.txt
```

Comment: Как можно добавить верхнее и нижнее поле. Что бы оно не повторялось как основное, а было уникальное?
{
"MainHead": Some ping",
"pings":[ 
.......
.......
],
"total": {
"good": 5,
"bad": 2,
"percents": 61.23,
"time": "127ms"
}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat  ./text.txt | egrep '^(not|ok)' | perl -pe 's/^((not\s+)?ok)\s+(\d+)\s+([^)]+\)),\s+(\d+)ms$/{"head":"$4","result":"$1","time":$5}/g; s/"ok"/true/g; s/"not ok"/false/g' | jq -s . |  jq -n '.pings |= [inputs]' | jq ".MainHead=\"$(cat ./text.txt | egrep -m 1 -B 1 '^-{70,}' | head -1 | perl -pe 's/^\[([^]]*)\].*$/$1/')\"" | jq ".total={\"good\":$(cat ./text.txt | egrep '^ok' | wc -l),"bad":$(cat ./text.txt | egrep '^not ok' | wc -l),"percents":$(echo `cat ./text.txt | egrep '^ok' | wc -l`' / ('`cat ./text.txt | egrep '^not ok' | wc -l`' +'`cat ./text.txt | egrep '^ok' | wc -l`') * 100' | bc -l)}"
```

- `cat ./text.txt` выводит на экран файл
- `egrep '^(not|ok)'` фильтрует тело файла отсекая заголовок и конец
- `perl ...` преобразует строку в почти JSON
- далее я заменяю `ok` на `true` и `not ok` на `false` (вероятно, не самый оптимальный способ, но одноразово пойдет)
- `jq -s .` делает остальную работу по формированию валидного JSON
- второй `jq` обрамляет массив в объект с свойством `pings`
- третий `jq` добавляет поле `MainHead`.
- четвертый `jq` добавляет поле `total`.

Внутри третьего jq немного жёстковатый код. Параметры `-m 1` и `-B 1` означают только первое соответствие и затронуть одну строчку до соответствия, само регулярное выражение `'^-{70,}'` ищет строку где есть 70 и более дефисов от начала строки, `head -1` отбирает первую строку из `egrep`, `perl` выбирает всё что в квадратных скобочках.

Внутри четвертого `jq` используется `bc` для подсчетов процентов.
Сумму времени добавлю позже.

Вроде норм. Правда поле MainHead добавилось в конец JSON. У меня получился вывод:

```
{
  "pings": [
    [
      {
        "head": "********* ****** ******* ************ (**** ***)",
        "result": false,
        "time": 6
      },
      {
        "head": "********* ****** ******* ************ (*** ** ** ***, *** ***)",
        "result": false,
        "time": 24
      },
      {
        "head": "********* ****** ***** (*** ** ** ***, *** ***)",
        "result": true,
        "time": 21
      },
      {
        "head": "********* ****** ******* **** (**** ***)",
        "result": true,
        "time": 10
      },
      {
        "head": "********* ****** ******* **** (*** ** ** ***, *** ***)",
        "result": true,
        "time": 17
      },
      {
        "head": "********* ****** ******* ****** (**** ***)",
        "result": true,
        "time": 11
      },
      {
        "head": "********* ****** ******* ****** (*** ** ** ***, *** ***)",
        "result": true,
        "time": 28
      }
    ]
  ],
  "MainHead": " Some ping ",
  "total": {
     "good": 5,
     "bad": 2,
     "percents": 71.42857142857143
   }
}
```

Comment: Вы реально мозг! Спасибо огромное! 
Осталось теперь мне этот заголовок и конец добавить. {
"MainHead": Some ping",
"pings":[
.........
.......
],
"total": {
"good": 5,
"bad": 2,
"percents": 61.23,
"time": "127ms"
}
}

Comment: Рад был помочь. Если что не понятно, пишите коммент, я могу сделать более подробное описание.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз. А как можно добавить верхнее и нижнее поле. Что бы оно не повторялось как основное, а было уникальное? Если я добавляю в это поле {{.......}"head":"$4",} То соответственно у меня оно во всех строчках появляется. А мне нужно это только вверху и внизу { "MainHead": Some ping", "pings":[ ....... ....... ], "total": { "good": 5, "bad": 2, "percents": 61.23, "time": "127ms" } }
Я предполагаю, что нужно это сделать в новую строчку без цикла -p и потом все это совместить.

Comment: @SUd0 тотал тоже добавил

Comment: по сути, в шелле почти нет никаких средств по работе с числами, приходится использовать `bc` или `dc`, но в обработке строк `bash+perl` нет равных, `sed` в 95% проигрывает `perl` в производительности, `jq` очень мощный инструмент для работы с JSON из шелла. Конечно, для более глубокой работы с JSON приоритетнее использовать `node`. Но, код получится чуть более  большим и сама команда не будет выглядеть такой "магической"

Comment: @SUd0 если сохранить начальный JSON во временный файл, который можно создать командой `mktemp`, то статистику `total` можно легко подсчитать с помощью [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) не прибегая к `bc` или `dc`. Там есть все средства по работе с математикой: можно подсчитывать количества, суммы, есть `.map()`, `.forEach()`,все тригонометрические функции, даже рекурсивный обход данных

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек!)